# Mongoid: select embedded objects that fits number of options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have got this structure

```
class House
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :inhabitants
end

class Inhabitant
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :house
  field :name
  field :gender
  field :age
end
```

I can get all houses where females live:

```
houses = House.where("inhabitants.gender" => "female")
```

But how can I get all houses where females under age 50 live? How can I specify more than one condition for embedded object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To apply multiple conditions to each entry in an array, you should use the `$elemMatch` operator. I'm not familiar with Mongoid, but here's the MongoDB shell syntax for your query modified to use `$elemMatch`:

```
> db.house.find({inhabitants: {$elemMatch: {gender: "female", age: {$lt: 50}}}})
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks! Mongoid syntax: `House.where({inhabitants: {"$elemMatch" => {gender: "female", age: {"$lt" => 50}}}})`

Comment: Alternate Mongoid (Origin) syntax: `House.elem_match(inhabitants: {gender: 'female', :age.lt => 50})`

Comment: @dcrosta I had been struggling for last 2 hours... Thanks for the solution. I had similar situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
houses = House.where("inhabitants.gender" => "female", "inhabitants.age" => {"$lt" => 50})
```

**Combining conditions**:
MongoDB query:

```
db.houses.find({'inhabitants.age' : {$in: {$lt: 50}}})
```

Mongoid:

```
houses = House.where('inhabitants.age' => {'$in' => {'$lt' => 50}})
```

Comment: I've already tried this. But this searches through all inhabittants, not through each.

Comment: You want to fetch all houses where at least 1 female under age 50 live?

Comment: yeap. Actually I want to know how can I fetch through embedded objects with more than one option.